# Definition of (g,K)-module

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup, and $\frak{g}, \frak{k}$ be their respective Lie algebras.

A $({\frak{g}},K)$-module is defined as a complex vector space $V$ that $\frak{g}$ and $K$ both acts on, such that

1. For any $Y \in \frak{k}$, $v \in V$
   $$Yv = \left(\exp(tY)v\right)'(0)$$
2. $V$ is $K$-finite, and
3. For any $k \in K$, $X \in \frak{g}$, we have
   $$(Ad(k)X)v = k(X(k^{-1}v))$$

I am confused about the third condition. According to Knapp-Trapa's "Representation theory of semi-simple Lie groups" or other sources, the third condition is really addressing the compatibility of the two actions when $K$ is disconnected.

> How to prove that 3 follows from 1 and 2 when $K$ is connected?

It's clear that we can reduce to the case where $k = \exp(Y)$ for some $Y \in \frak{k}$. I am  not sure how I can proceed afterwards - I tried to look at $(Ad(\exp(tY))X)v$ versus $\exp(tY) \cdot X \cdot \exp(-tY)v$ and hope that some uniqueness results of ODE may work, but then I realize that I cannot guarantee the map
$$t \to (Ad(\exp(tY))X) v$$
is even smooth to start with.

Any help, hint, or reference would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $Ad(tY)X$? Is it $ad(tY)X=t[Y,X]$ or $Ad(exp(tY))X$?

Comment: @rafaelm, I meant $Ad(exp(tY))X$, thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: Then the map $t \mapsto (Ad(exp(tY))X)v$ is smooth because it is composed of smooth maps, namely  $t \mapsto Ad(exp(tY))X$ (from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathfrak{g}$), and $Z \mapsto Z \cdot v$ ($\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g} \cdot v$). The latter one is smooth because it is a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @rafaelm, stupid me, thanks! Somehow I keep thinking that I need some smoothness condition to guarantee that.

In that case, it looks like I can use the analyticity of $t \to (Ad\exp(tY)X) v$ and $t \to \exp(tY)\cdot X \cdot \exp(-tY) \cdot v$ (since $v$ is $K$-finite), and just compute that their Taylor series at 0 are the same. Am I right?